# How to detect an operator like '[' in a character-variable

Tags: r, operators, character, subset, split

Let's say I have character variables like `"var"` and `"var[1]"`. How could I detect whether there are operators `[]` in the character?

I have been looking into `strsplit` and `agrep` but so far without succes..

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What are you doing? What errors are you getting? Is it just because square brackets are special characters in grep and you have to do `grepl("\\[",x)` to match them?

Comment: I have written a function, which in some rare cases might give unexpected results when data is provided in subset form (ie `data[1,]`), so I want give a warning when data is entered like that.

Comment: Redesign your function. There is a better way to handle this.

Comment: @Roland : I will surely redesign my function, this is just a temporary fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial regexp escaping of special characters:

```
> x=c("var","var[1]")
> grepl("\\[",x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Read up on regular expressions: `help(regexp)`

Answer (score 1):

To get values finded with their index:

```
 x <- "var[22]"
 m <- regexpr("\\[.*\\]", x, perl=TRUE)
 > regmatches(x, m)
 [1] "[22]"
```

Or to get values:

```
 > grep("\\[.*\\]", c("var[2]"), perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
 [1] "var[2]"
```

to get index:

```
> grep("\\[.*\\]", c("var[2]"), perl=TRUE, value=FALSE)
[1] 1
```